# Not able to access Remote EJB from the client (Junit ) .LookUp is failing

Tags: java, junit, ejb, geronimo

I am new to EJB as well as Geronimo server.
I want to create Junit POC for EJB on Geronimo Server.
But on Lookup to Stateless Session bean its giving me this error.

Please find the exception below

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot lookup '/MyStatelessSessionBeanRemote'. [Root exception is java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot read the response from the server. The class for an object being returned is not located in this system:; nested exception is:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sampleear.RemoteBusinessInterface]
at org.apache.openejb.client.JNDIContext.lookup(JNDIContext.java:240)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:363)
at test.SampleTest.setUp(SampleTest.java:44)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
```

I am using Geronimo server 2.1 and I have also deployed the EAR file in geronimo server.
EAR file gets successfully deployed showing on the Geronimo server.

Please find the Logs below

```
2019-07-01 14:39:46,221 INFO  [config] Configuring Service(id=Default BMP Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default BMP Container)
2019-07-01 14:39:46,222 INFO  [config] Configuring Service(id=Default CMP Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default CMP Container)
2019-07-01 14:39:46,222 INFO  [config] Configuring app: sampleear/sample-ejb/1.0/ejb
2019-07-01 14:39:46,269 INFO  [OpenEJB] Auto-deploying ejb MyStatelessSessionBean: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=sample-ejb/MyStatelessSessionBean)
2019-07-01 14:39:46,277 INFO  [config] Loaded Module: sampleear/sample-ejb/1.0/ejb
2019-07-01 14:39:46,555 INFO  [startup] Assembling app: /tmp/geronimo-deployer1011310413181662917.tmpdir/SampleEJB.jar
2019-07-01 14:39:46,557 ERROR [startup] Jndi(name=MyStatelessSessionBeanRemote) cannot be bound to Ejb(deployment-id=sample-ejb/MyStatelessSessionBean).  Name already taken by Ejb(deployment-id=SampleEJB.jar/MyStatelessSessionBean)
2019-07-01 14:39:46,557 INFO  [startup] Created Ejb(deployment-id=sample-ejb/MyStatelessSessionBean, ejb-name=MyStatelessSessionBean, container=Default Stateless Container)
2019-07-01 14:39:46,558 INFO  [startup] Deployed Application(path=/tmp/geronimo-deployer1011310413181662917.tmpdir/SampleEJB.jar)
2019-07-01 14:39:46,673 INFO  [SupportedModesServiceImpl] Portlet mode 'edit' not found for portletId: '/plugin.Deployment!227983155|0'
2019-07-01 14:39:46,676 INFO  [XSRFHandler] Updated HTML content with XSRF JavaScript for requestURI=/console/portal//Applications/Deploy%20New
```

Junit - Client

```
public class SampleTest extends TestCase {

  protected MyStatelessSessionBean remoteBusinessIntf;


  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
    prop.put("java.naming.provider.url", "ejbd://127.0.0.1:4201");
//    prop.put("openejb.authentication.realmName","geronimo-admin");
//    prop.put("java.naming.security.principal","system");
//    prop.put("java.naming.security.credentials","manager");
    Context context = new InitialContext(prop);
    remoteBusinessIntf = (MyStatelessSessionBean) context.lookup("MyStatelessSessionBeanRemote"); // Giving error on this.

}

public void testSaveBook() {
        System.out.println("ok");
        remoteBusinessIntf.sayHello("EJB");
    }

}
```

---

```
Stateless Session Bean

package sampleear;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class MyStatelessSessionBean implements RemoteBusinessInterface {
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return getClass().getName() + " says hello to "+ name + ".";
    }
}
```

---

Remote Interface

```
package sampleear;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface RemoteBusinessInterface {
    public String sayHello(String name);
}
```

---

Deployed EJB Application

```
 Component Name      State  Commands
 org.apache.geronimo.configs/mejb/2.1.4/car      running     Stop    Restart     Uninstall 
 org.apache.geronimo.plugins/agent/2.1.4/car     running     Stop    Restart     Uninstall 
 sampleear/sample-ejb/1.0/ejb    running     Stop    Restart     Uninstall
```

Geronimo v2.1.4

No Modifications to port.Default Port is used.

---

Port Details of Geronimo

```
Startup completed in 31.119s seconds
  Listening on Ports:
    1050 0.0.0.0 CORBA Naming Service
    1099 0.0.0.0 RMI Naming
    1527 0.0.0.0 Derby Connector
    2001 0.0.0.0 OpenEJB ORB Adapter
    4201 0.0.0.0 OpenEJB Daemon
    6882 0.0.0.0 OpenEJB ORB Adapter
    8009 0.0.0.0 Tomcat Connector AJP AJP
    8080 0.0.0.0 Tomcat Connector HTTP BIO HTTP
    8443 0.0.0.0 Tomcat Connector HTTPS BIO HTTPS
    9999 0.0.0.0 JMX Remoting Connector
   61613 0.0.0.0 ActiveMQ Transport Connector
   61616 0.0.0.0 ActiveMQ Transport Connector
```

---

I have again created the fresh Geronimo server and deployed the EJB Application.This time haven't got any deployment error. Please find the logs below.

```
2019-07-02 10:28:18,242 INFO  [config] Configuring Service(id=Default Stateful Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateful Container)
2019-07-02 10:28:18,242 INFO  [config] Configuring Service(id=Default BMP Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default BMP Container)
2019-07-02 10:28:18,242 INFO  [config] Configuring Service(id=Default CMP Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default CMP Container)
2019-07-02 10:28:18,243 INFO  [config] Configuring app: sampleear/sample-ejb/1.0/ejb
2019-07-02 10:28:18,275 INFO  [OpenEJB] Auto-deploying ejb MyStatelessSessionBean: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=sample-ejb/MyStatelessSessionBean)
2019-07-02 10:28:18,281 INFO  [config] Loaded Module: sampleear/sample-ejb/1.0/ejb
2019-07-02 10:28:18,555 INFO  [startup] Assembling app: /tmp/geronimo-deployer7186189966556040174.tmpdir/SampleEJB.jar
2019-07-02 10:28:18,558 INFO  [startup] Jndi(name=MyStatelessSessionBeanRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=sample-ejb/MyStatelessSessionBean)
2019-07-02 10:28:18,558 INFO  [startup] Created Ejb(deployment-id=sample-ejb/MyStatelessSessionBean, ejb-name=MyStatelessSessionBean, container=Default Stateless Container)
2019-07-02 10:28:18,558 INFO  [startup] Deployed Application(path=/tmp/geronimo-deployer7186189966556040174.tmpdir/SampleEJB.jar)
2019-07-02 10:28:18,669 INFO  [SupportedModesServiceImpl] Portlet mode 'edit' not found for portletId: '/plugin.Deployment!227983155|0'
2019-07-02 10:28:18,673 INFO  [XSRFHandler] Updated HTML content with XSRF JavaScript for requestURI=/console/portal//Applications/Deploy%20New
```

Comment: The EJBs from version 2.0 are not necessary to deploy to test them. They are simple POJO-s with annotations. Use Mockito to create your test : https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

Comment: Have a look at the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-intro004.htm) on how the JNDI lookups work, especially the naming scheme. However, I'd recommend either using some embedded container (e.g. via  [Arquilian](http://arquillian.org/features/)) to test the EJBs or alternatively access them via webservices. I'd not recommend remote access over RMI for security reasons and others.

Comment: @The Bitman, thanks for your quick response.I am quiet familier will Junit and Mock.
I am refering http://www.laliluna.de/articles/posts/junit-testing-ejb-tutorial.html Link for creating junit for geronimo server.
As the above link suggested the standard way to lookup the remote server and then make the remote call.
please help with this.

Comment: @Thomas I have already gone through the Oracle tutorial ,and tried all the possible ways, but no luck.It was giving the exceptions.
Is there some way in which this can be resolved.

Comment: Well, there is a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sampleear.RemoteBusinessInterface` which should be pretty self-explanatory?

Comment: @TheBitman ,Actually the project I am working is on Geronimo server,and for this I need to implement Junit.So for this I am creating a small POC on Geronimo server.But failing.It will be really helpful If you help me with the current environment setup.

Comment: `Jndi(name=MyStatelessSessionBeanRemote) cannot be bound to Ejb(deployment-id=sample-ejb/MyStatelessSessionBean).  Name already taken by Ejb(deployment-id=SampleEJB.jar/MyStatelessSessionBean)` - this error indicates a problem with your deployment. If possible please post details on that, e.g. what's deployed, what version of Geronimo you're using etc.

Comment: Is the port number right? A s I can see this is the default one. Din not modify it during the server installation?

Comment: @Thomas Please find details below,it contains the jar deployed on geronimo.

_______________________________________________________
 

Component Name   State  Commands
 org.apache.geronimo.configs/mejb/2.1.4/car    running    Stop    Restart    Uninstall 
 org.apache.geronimo.plugins/agent/2.1.4/car    running    Stop    Restart    Uninstall 
 sampleear/sample-ejb/1.0/ejb    running    Stop    Restart    Uninstall

_________________________________________________________

Also The Geronimo version I am using is Geronimo 2.1.4,

no port no modifications made during installation.

Comment: Instead of adding such information in a comment please do so via an [edit] to your question. That way you're better able to format it and others will see it much easier too.

Comment: @Thomas, I will add those conf details in Question section.Thanks

Comment: @Thomas , I have added configuration details in Question Section.Please help me with this.I am blocked over this issue.

Comment: Well, Geronimo 2.1.4 seems to support only up to JavaEE 5 which didn't yet include the jndi name standard. Since I'm no expert on Geronimo you'd need to either have a look at the documentation or at some management ui (like JBoss' management or jmx console) or upgrade to a version that supports JavaEE 6 which the Oracle tutorial refers to.

Comment: @Thomas ,As per its https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/overview008.htm oracle docs . JNDI is included in JAVAEE7. 
But after deploying Jar JNDI name gets created ,in that case if JAVAEE 5 does not support JNDI, then JNDI name creation should fail ?
Is there any other alternative to make a remote EJB call without JNDI lookup?

Comment: No, JavaEE 5 supports JNDI as well. However, each implementation/application server had its own naming scheme. As of JavaEE 6 some conventions on the naming have been introduced so either upgrade your server to be able to use those conventions or look up on how Geronimo does it in the version you're using.

Comment: @Thomas , I referd https://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/deploying-and-running-ejb-application-clients.html for creating the EJB project.
I am not able to figure it out,which naming conventions to use for Geronimo 2.1.4 JavaEE5 conf.It will be really helpful If you share some links or naming convention sample.As I am also newbie to Geronimo and EJB.

Comment: @Thomas , I came accross https://coderanch.com/t/562066/java/ejb-application-client-find-session which contains the same issue which I am facing right now, But there is no solution mention.  Not sure if it's still problem or not.
https://community.oracle.com/thread/841694 
Can you please help me with the solution.

Comment: As I said I'm no expert on Geronimo since I mostly work with JBoss/Wildfly. However, if you're new to EJB why are you using that old a version of Geronimo? I'd assume the reason could be that the application already exists and can't run on a newer version (or the company/customer won't want to do that). However, in that case there should be someone who developed the application in the first place so can't you ask them?

Comment: One more info: I've found [this thread](http://apache-geronimo.328035.n3.nabble.com/JNDI-Name-for-EJB3-td341270.html) which might help and states "The jndi names are printed out in var/log/geronimo.log as the ejbs start." - you might want to have a look at that file (although depending on your setup the location might be different).